# How to make all the buttons in a page accessible through keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a basic webpage consisting of only buttons but i want to make the buttons accessible through only keyboard for convenience in accessibility... Please help. This is the code of the page

```
<table  border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="5px">
<tr>
  <td><button class="1" style="height:auto" onClick="#" onKeyDown="myFunction()">Milk Collection</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><button class="1" onClick="#")> Local Sale</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><button class="1" onClick="#")> Utilities</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><button class="1" onClick="#")> Master</button></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I don't know whether your browser is complaining about this, but you have extra brackets in your html that do not belong; ie `<button class="1" onClick="#")>` should be `<button class="1" onClick="#">`

Comment: Its fine..It was done by mistake at the time of posting question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this can help you

```
window.onkeydown = function(e) {
    var key = e.keyCode;
    if (key === 13) {
        //Enter key
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

an easy way to create keyboard shortcuts is using this ['shortcut' plugin](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/shortcut.js)

here's an example of how to use it;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/shortcut.js"></script>

<script>
    shortcut.add("alt+s", function() {
        // Do something
    });   
    shortcut.add("ctrl+enter", function() {
        // Do something
    }); 
</script>
```

If you don't want to use any third party plugins (except jquery), you can use the one max gave; At this moment the keypress event doesn't work in Google Chrome nor Safari, but if you use keydown they'll work on all browsers.

```
$(window).keydown(function(e) {
    var code = e.which || e.keyCode; //<--edit, some browsers will not give a keyCode
    switch (code) {
        case 37: case 38:  //key is left or up
            if (currImage <= 1) {break;} //if is the first one do nothing
            goToPrev(); // function which goes to previous image
            return false; //"return false" will avoid further events
        case 39: case 40: //key is left or down
            if (currImage >= maxImages) {break;} //if is the last one do nothing
            goToNext(); // function which goes to next image
            return false; //"return false" will avoid further events
    }
    return; //using "return" other attached events will execute
});
```

to find out the `keyCode` for the keys you want to use, you can just `alert(e.keyCode);` in the above function and then add the case for your key sequence.

Comment: Thnx for your time.But still i m not getting. My current button **Milk Sale** is focued and on press of keydown it should go to the next button which is **Local Sale** and so on.

Comment: ok which solution are you using and can you edit the question and add your code to it please, I'll have a look at it soon

Answer (score 1):

**html:**

```
 <button class="1" style="height:auto"  onkeydown="myFunction(event)">Milk Collection</button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
 function myFunction(e) { // Trigger the click event from the keyboard
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert("click");
        return false;
    }
 }
```